# simple distinct column, can't get my head around it

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have the following query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, ID, IMAGE_1, IMAGE_1_DESCRIPTION
FROM PHOTO_GALLERY
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Of course it is bringing up all the entries, but I want it to filter out any that have the same TITLE field, choosing just the lowest ID

I've seen there are a few questions that are similar to this query, but I just can't seem to work out the answer to my problem by studying them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `group by`, not a `distinct`.  To get the lowest id:

```
SELECT TITLE, min(ID) as minid
FROM PHOTO_GALLERY
group by title
ORDER BY minID ASC
```

To get the rest of the information, you will need to join the table back in.  Here is a version with the explicit join:

```
SELECT pg.TITLE, pg.ID, pg.IMAGE_1, pg.IMAGE_1_DESCRIPTION
FROM PHOTO_GALLERY pg join
     (SELECT TITLE, min(ID) as minid
      FROM PHOTO_GALLERY
      group by title
     ) pgt
     on pg.title = pgt.title and pg.id = pgt.minid
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: wow! That is great man! I really appreciate it. It sounded such a simple thing to do but I haven;t got my head anywhere near as complex a query as that before. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The select does a cartesian product of the tables in the "from" bit. "Where" knocks those out that do not satisfy the clause. "order by" sorts the rest. Into the mix is distinct - you get the first row that is not identical to the next.

So add a where clause on the title and use LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Distinct returns unique rows for specified set of columns. Maybe you should try to use this as subquery:

```
select min(id), title from photo_gallery group by title
```